# How to set custom properties in the currently active Word document via OpenXML

Tags: c#, vsto, openxml, office-interop

So far I've been able to set custom properties to a Word doc by using VSTO and by adding a package stream to the active document as it follows

```
public static void SetCustomProperty(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc, string propertyName, object propertyValue)
{
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    using ((WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Create(stream,  WordprocessingDocumentType.Document, true))
    {
        SetProperty(wordDoc, propertyName, propertyValue);
        // Flush the contents of the package.
        wordDoc.Package.Flush();
        // Convert back to flat OPC by using this in-memory package.
        XDocument xDoc = OpcHelper.OpcToFlatOpc(wordDoc.Package);
        // Return the xml string.
        string openxml = xDoc.ToString();
        // Add to Word doc
        doc.CustomXMLParts.Add(openxml);
    }
}
```

The `SetProperty` method works as explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff936167%28v=office.14%29.aspx) and the OpcHelper can be found [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Improve-Automation-415bff13) and is explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff191178.aspx).

The problem is that my custom property is inserted in a xml file (e.g. item1.xml) that is located in the folder *document.zip\customXml* of the OpenXML file format. Later on when I want to read my custom property I use the `WordProcessingDocument.CustomFilePropertiesPart` which is empty. In fact I found that `CustomFilePropertiesPart` references the *document.zip\docProps\custom.xml* file.

So instead of using `doc.CustomXMLParts.Add(openxml);` what should I use to populate the right xml file, i.e. *document.zip\docProps\custom.xml*?

**EDIT**
I tried already the solution proposed by Mishra without success, i.e custom properties were not always saved. However since he posted this solution I tried again and I found [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/195425/en-us?fr=1) that you firstly need to mark the document as unsaved:

```
doc.CustomDocumentProperties.Add("MyProp", False, MsoDocProperties.msoPropertyTypeNumber, 123);
doc.Saved = false;
doc.Save();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cant set custome properties using CustomXMLParts collection. If you have document open better keep it simple and use CustomDocumentProperties collection, its quite fast and easy. I would use open XML in open doc only if the data to insert is vary large.

Comment: Thanks, this works but you need to mark the document as unsaved in order to be sure to save the custom properties. See my edits